# Is this series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{{1 \over n} \cos{(n)} \sin{(nx)}}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How can I show that the following series is convergent or divergent ?

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{{1 \over n} \cos{(n)} \sin{(nx)}},x\in \mathbb{R}$$

I want to use Abel-Dirichlet criteria. I've already noticed that $1 \over n$ decreases to zero, and is $>0$ for any $x$ bigger than $1$. The problem is that I do not know how to show that $\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos{(n)} \sin{(nx)}}$ has a bounded sequence of partial sums. Can you please help me? While trying to show the boundedness of this series I used $\color{red}{\sin(x+y)-\sin(x-y)=2\cos (x) \sin (y)}$   formula, but could not get anything.

Comment: is it $\cos n$ or $\cos nx$

Comment: it's cosn, as in my exercise book

Comment: what is $x$ @John

Comment: sorry , I added, it's a constant

Comment: You are one the right path with Abel-Dirichlet's criteria. Now, think complex!

Comment: @D.Thomine What do you mean ?

Comment: Can you express $cos(n) sin(nx)$ as the real part of $e^{\theta n}$ for some well-chosen complex $\theta$? If so, what does it tells you about the partial sums?

Comment: The sequence of partial sums is bounded, is it ?

Comment: Yes, it is bounded. My previous comment was a bit rough. Have a look at $Im (e^{in(x+1)}+e^{in(x-1)})/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the case to notice that:
$$ \cos n \sin(nx) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(n(x+1))+\sin(n(x-1))\right),$$
and since for any $z\in(0,2\pi)$ we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nz)}{n}=\frac{\pi-z}{2}, $$
it follows that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos n}{n}\,\sin(nx)$$
is a $2\pi$-periodic function, discontinuous in $x=1$ and $x=2\pi-1$, elsewhere differentiable with derivative $-1$:

[image]

Since such a function vanishes for $x\in \pi\mathbb{Z}$, we have, for any $x$:
$$\left|\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos n}{n}\,\sin(nx)\right|\leq\color{red}{\pi-1}.$$